# DataInputStream isn't reading properly?

Tags: java, datainputstream

I'm fairly new to both Java programming & stack overflow, and this morning ive been having a big trouble with following simple code. It has 3 options, add new user to a binary file, list every user on it and searching a specific user to show every other data related to it (last name & year born):

```
case 1: System.out.println("Introduce nombre: ");
        nombre=teclado.next();
        System.out.println("Introduce apellido: ");
        apellido=teclado.next();
        System.out.println("Introduce año de nacimiento: ");
        nacido=teclado.nextInt();
        dos.writeUTF(nombre);
        dos.writeUTF(apellido);
        dos.writeInt(nacido);
        break;
case 2: try {
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("file.bin");
            DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(fis);
            while (dis.available()>0) {
                   System.out.println(dis.readUTF()+" "+dis.readUTF()+" nació en "+dis.readInt());
            }
            fis.close();
       }
       catch (EOFException e) {System.out.println("Fin del fichero.");}
       break;
case 3: System.out.println("Introduce el nombre a buscar: ");
        String buscar=teclado.next();
        try {
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("file.bin");
            DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(fis);
            while (dis.available()>0) {
                   if (buscar.compareTo(dis.readUTF())==0) {
                           System.out.println("Los datos completos del usuario son: "+dis.readUTF()+" "+dis.readUTF()+" que nació el "+dis.readInt());
                           break;
                   }
            }
            fis.close();
        }
        catch (EOFException e) {System.out.println("user not found.");}
        break;
```

Add user & list them all are working ok, however the searching option isn't.
In case 2 loop is reading fine the whole file though on case 3 it is Reading just 1-2 words and already shows the "user not found", any advice on why?

Regards.

Comment: `available()` is not a test for end of stream. See the Javadoc.

Comment: I havent found any other way beside the infinite loop `while(true)`. Used the `available()>0` because it was working fine on case 2, reading whole stuff inside the file. Any suggestions about a proper way to end the stream?

Comment: You 'end the stream' by closing the socket. You're conflating end of stream with end of message. If you want messages over TCP you have to implement them yourself, with lines, length-word prefixes, type-length-value messages, serialization, XML, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is that your `user not found` message is printed when there is an unexpected end of file.

This means that you try to read from file when there is nothing else left to read.

The problem lies in this chunk of code:

```
if (buscar.compareTo(dis.readUTF())==0) {
                           System.out.println("Los datos completos del usuario son: "+dis.readUTF()+" "+dis.readUTF()+" que nació el "+dis.readInt());
                           break;
                   }
```

Here you read **once** to compare and then **attempt to read again** in order to print out (and that is the problem).

What you need to do is to read each field only once - and assign its value to a variable if you want to use it again (e.g. print).

So, something like this, should work:

```
String first=dis.readUTF();
String second=dis.readUTF();
int    third=dis.readInt();
if (buscar.compareTo(first)==0) {
                           System.out.println("Los datos completos del usuario son: "+first+" "+second+" que nació el "+third);
                           break;
                   }
```

*By the way, in your implementation - there is high probability that user will not be found - but because no `Exception` will be thrown - no message will be displayed either - you should fix that too.

Comment: Tried so this morning, but as the file got data on fields like these: UTF UTF INT UTF UTF INT etc... I'll get an exception and "user not found" again when hes trying to read the third field, an int, using a readUTF. I havent figure out how to skip/read only one of the three fields (they dont have any separator on the file itselfs), or to check every field on file, first / last names & born date.

Comment: @Stephan ok now that you've provided more information I've edited the solution. Just read 3 values each time (no matter what).  Compare with first and if equal print all of them.

Comment: I didnt catch what u meant with: "there is high probability that user will not be found - but because no Exception will be thrown - no message will be displayed either"   If he doesnt find id, it will display always the "user not found" when reaching the end of file, right?

Comment: @Stephan what I meant was if your `dis.available()` returns `0` at some point then you have reached the end of file - but no exception will be thrown...

Comment: @Plirkee `available()` returning zero means there is *no data available to be read without blocking.* This is **NOT** the same as end of file, or end of stream. See the Javadoc.